# Output "file--token--entity" using Stanford NER

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to use Stanford NER in C# to read all files in a folder and output the result into one file in the format "file  token  entity"

Here is what I have:

```c#
namespace stanfordNER
{
    class Program
    {
        public static CRFClassifier Classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(@"english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("directory address?");
            string dir = Console.ReadLine();

            //Reads all files in directory
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                //Get the document name
                string docNo = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetFullPath(f).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
                Console.WriteLine(docNo);

                string docText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f); 

                var classified = Classifier.classifyFile(f).toArray();

                //Error here when running
                //Should output the entities,**this part is the work of Stewart Whiting (STEWH)
                for (int i = 0; i < classified.Length; i++)
                {
                    Triple triple = (Triple)classified[i];

                    int second = Convert.ToInt32(triple.second().ToString());
                    int third = Convert.ToInt32(triple.third().ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine(docNo + '\t' + triple.first().ToString() + '\t' +                              docText.Substring(second, third - second));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a invalid cast exception error at "triple".  I don't understand how to use the triple function.

example of the output I want:

```html
wiki-ms      ORGANIZATION    Microsoft Corporation
wiki-ms      LOCATION        Redmond
wiki-ms      LOCATION        Washington
wiki-ms      ORGANIZATION    Microsoft
wiki-ms      ORGANIZATION    Microsoft Office
wiki-ms      ORGANIZATION    Microsoft
wiki-ms      PERSON          Bill Gates
wiki-ms      PERSON          Paul Allen
wiki-ms      ORGANIZATION    Microsoft
wiki-ms      ORGANIZATION    Microsoft
```

Thanks in advance!  I'm a manufacturing engineer so my programming knowledge is pretty bad.

If you have a way to filter duplicates and/or similar entities that would be an added bonus!

Thanks to Stewart Whiting. [His Site](http://www.stewh.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just had to change

`var classified = Classifier.classifyFile(f).toArray();`

to

```
var classified = Classifier.classifyToCharacterOffsets(docText).toArray();
```

thanks.